# Comando para a partilha mesma pasta com vários nomes

Tags: windows, linha-de-comando

Atualmente estou trabalhando em uma melhoria no processo de implantação e eu gostaria de automatizar um dos novos passos.

Através do *Windows UI* eu posso compartilhar a mesma pasta na rede sob vários nomes diferentes.

No prompt de comando ha um comando para a partilha (`NET SHARE _shared $ = c: \ Exemplo`), mas só permite adicionar um nome para a pasta compartilhada.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso por meio de programação, como com a API do Windows ou até mesmo WMI?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta:

> No prompt de comando ha um comando para a partilha (NET SHARE _shared $ = c: \ Exemplo), mas só permite adicionar um nome para a pasta compartilhada.

Você precisará adicionar o comando [Net share] quantas vezes for preciso para cada pasta compartilhada.

Maiores detalhes em: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx

Sua pergunta:

> Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso por meio de programação, como com a API do Windows ou até mesmo WMI?

Você poderá utilizar um arquivo *.bat ou mesmo o PowerShell.

Dica: Criando scripts - iniciando. Por Daniel Donda
http://www.mcsesolution.com/Scripting-Batch/scripts-mais-poderoso.html

## IMPORTANTE:

- Não se esqueça de utilizar o $ (compartilhado oculto) para não exibir
  as pastas compartilhadas nos computadores remotos. Você somente acessará sabendo o nome da pasta compartilhada;
- Não é recomendável este tipo de compartilhamento (Net share). Ele é
  muito vulnerável dentro de sua rede;
- O mais seguro procedimento é a instalação de um servidor de arquivos, quer seja pela segurança ou mesmo pela centralização de todos backups dos setores e usuários da organização.